# Reset grafana/ui AsyncSelect value

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I have AsyncSelect component on my plugin and I want to reset it, when other input was changed.

I tried set id to empty string, null, undefined and delete from query object before pass to handleQueryChange method, but nothing worked for me. I see changed query in logs, but component doesn't changed

```js
const handleMinionIdChange = (item: SelectableValue<string>) => {
    if (query.minionId !== item.value) {
      const {id, ...changedQuery} = query
      handleQueryChange({...changedQuery, minionId: item.value!}, false);
    }
  };
```